# What does it mean to give somebody "a less than favorable review"?

Tags: meaning-in-context, sentence-meaning

> It feels awkward to give a famous author a less than favorable review.

Comment: The complete phrase is 'give someone **a less than favorable review**'.

Comment: For greater clarity, the phrase could have been written "give a famous author a less-than-favorable review."

Comment: Probably a better followup for ELU, but isn't this supposed to be hyphenated?

Comment: it means give a review that is not very good; it could mean a review that is bad, but not too bad; and it could also mean give a review that's just plain bad

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The writer of the sentence is not *giving the author **a less***.

*Less* is not a noun.

The complete  noun phrase  is *a less than favorable review*. This is the direct object of *give*.

*Less than favorable* means *not favorable*.

Another way to write this is

The writer is giving the author *a review that is less than favorable.*

So

> a less than favorable review

equals

> a review that is less than  favorable

This is a  nice  way of saying

> a bad/negative review

Comment: I'm not sure it necessarily means 'bad/negative'. A neutral review is also 'less than favourable'.

Comment: @abligh Technically true, but I don't think I've ever seen it used for neutral; those are usually just stated plainly.

Comment: @abligh is right, a neutral or a mixed review, or even a *somewhat positive but not enthusiastic* review might be seen (by some people) as "less than favorable". I think in this specific case, if this is a famous/popular author, there will be plenty of people who gush about any new book, so it feels somewhat uncomfortable to give a review that is anything but enthusiastically positive.

Comment: @BradC If you expect gushing reviews, then anything that isn't enthusiastically positive is negative, at least from the author's point of view. But even from the reviewer's perspective, idiomatically, I think "less than X" in this context really means _so much_ less than X that even a "less than enthusiastically positive review" is a negative review.

Comment: Regardless of the logical plain meaning of the expression, "less than extremely good" is so widely used as a euphemism for "bad" that if you mean to convey a different meaning (such as "somewhere in the range from bad to mildly good") I would advise using different wording.

Comment: @abligh The question title was phrased in British English (favo**u**rable) even if the body of the question used the American spelling. British English often uses understatement for emphasis. ‘Less than favourable’ would typically mean ‘quite bad’ or ‘very bad’ on this side of the pond.

Comment: @Calchas I'm not quite sure which side of the pond you are on ('this side' is not helpful!), but I'm on the British side (hence the 'u' in my comment), and I'd take "less than favourable" as a euphemism - it need not necessarily be understatement. I'd take "bad" to be stronger than "less than favourable". "Less than favourable" could also include 'mixed' as far as I can see. The number 1 google hit (apart from this question) is an a review that starts (having apologised for a 'less than favourable review') *'I stopped into this pub ... last Saturday and have mixed feelings.'*

Comment: @abligh I split my time between them, but usually based in London (England). :) Let's put it this way, if I heard that my UK boss had rated my performance as ‘less than favourable’ I would clear my desk in the expectation of being fired. If my (hypothetical) US boss said the same I would expect a smaller bonus than usual.

Comment: @Calchas ah I see. Having worked in both, I agree that 'less than favourable' is more likely to be negative in Britain than it is in the US. Clearly the 'u' has some semantic value after all :-)

Comment: @abligh I assure you, understatement has the exact identical meaning and usage in US English, although it does have a distinct British "feel" to it. Although I agree that the likelihood is higher that someone using that phrase in the US may not have that intended meaning, but the meaning is still generally well understood in the US.

Comment: @abligh Two stars out of five (in the "less than favourable teview" [sic] of the Bricklayers Arms) is a _bad review._ That's consistent with how "less than favorable" sounds to my ear. I'm a lifelong resident of the US, so I don't think I'm especially inclined to take things as understatement when they're not meant that way.

Answer (score 13):

*"A less than  favourable" review* is an euphemistic way to say:

> - "a bad/negative" review.

Edit:

This follows the general pattern in English (as in other languages) of using "not very" to imply the opposite of what a modifier usually means:

> That building is not very tall (the building is not tall)
>
> His moral character is less than pristine (his moral character is not good)
>
> She doesn't think very highly of that movie (she has a low opinion of the movie)

The *nuance* varies between each of these.  The "not very" construction can imply *somewhat* the opposite or completely opposite depending on context.

In this example, a "less than favourable" review is a bad review.  The "less than" is a [*euphemism*](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/euphemism), a word or phrase that sounds better than it actually means.

As with many things in English, it's important to listen to how native speakers use this construction, and practice it yourself where appropriate.

Side note:  *Favourable* is the BrE spelling.  In AmE it's spelled *favorable*.

Comment: can you explain more please? I did not get it.

Comment: If you give a famous author a riview that is "less than favourable", that is "not favourable" is just a way to say "a bad or negative"  review.

Answer (score 5):

This expression is a great example of a common rhetorical device formally called [litotes](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/litotes), but more commonly known as "understatement". In this case "less than favorable" is a tongue-in-cheek way of saying "unfavorable" with the understanding that anything less than favorable is in a category of being not favorable. "Less than favorable" understates the fact that it is indeed the opposite of favorable.

Another example would be "I could(n't) care less", for which there is roaring and raging debate that only saying "couldn't" communicates the correct meaning of "I do not care".

A less controversial example would be "He was not a little surprised by her return", meaning "He was very surprised by her return".

Answer (score 3):

A "less than favorable review" could mean a **bad** review.

In the case of a famous author, it is likely to mean a "lukewarm" review. Something like "okay, but not great."

That is not a bad review, but not as good as one would expect, given that the author is famous.

This is known as ["damning with faint praise."](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Damning_with_faint_praise)

Comment: Something ok but not great might not be what you favour, so it is indeed not favourable :) Who has the time to read all the books that aren't horrible?